# Overlapping communicators and collective operations in MPI

Tags: mpi

This is an example from the MPI standard (version 4.1).

[image]

We have 3 processes and 3 communicators. The standard states that

> It is not possible to perform a blocking collective operation on all communicators because there exists no deadlock-free order to invoke them. However, nonblocking collective operations can easily be used to achieve this task.

And provides this code snippet

```c
MPI_Request reqs[2];

switch(rank) {
  case 0:
    MPI_Iallreduce(sbuf1, rbuf1, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm1, &reqs[0]);
    MPI_Iallreduce(sbuf3, rbuf3, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm3, &reqs[1]);
    break;
  case 1:
    MPI_Iallreduce(sbuf1, rbuf1, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm1, &reqs[0]);
    MPI_Iallreduce(sbuf2, rbuf2, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm2, &reqs[1]);
    break;
  case 2:
    MPI_Iallreduce(sbuf2, rbuf2, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm2, &reqs[0]);
    MPI_Iallreduce(sbuf3, rbuf3, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm3, &reqs[1]);
    break;
}
MPI_Waitall(2, reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
```

I see no deadlock in the blocking version of the same snippet, i.e. in

```c
switch(rank) {
  case 0:
    MPI_Allreduce(sbuf1, rbuf1, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm1);
    MPI_Allreduce(sbuf3, rbuf3, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm3);
    break;
  case 1:
    MPI_Allreduce(sbuf1, rbuf1, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm1);
    MPI_Allreduce(sbuf2, rbuf2, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm2);
    break;
  case 2:
    MPI_Allreduce(sbuf2, rbuf2, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm2);
    MPI_Allreduce(sbuf3, rbuf3, count, dtype, MPI_SUM, comm3);
    break;
}
```

So the timing diagram would approximately be

[image]

Am I missing something? Maybe by "deadlock" the standard doesn't mean a complete standstill.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock),

> If a process remains **indefinitely** unable to change its state because resources requested by it are being used by another process that itself is waiting, then the system is said to be in a deadlock.

(emphasis by me)

Comment: You may have a point! The best place to discuss this is by making a comment to the MPI Forum https://www.mpi-forum.org/comments/

Answer (score 0):

The standard is implying there is no guarantee this is deadlock free and assuming so is an incorrect program.

However, the MPI implementation is probably doing nonblocking operations under the covers such that is works but it's not standard compliant to assume that behavior and no guarantee some other MPI implementation will work or a more complicated example will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question is not about any particular MPI implementation. The question is whether the blocking version of this code **may** cause deadlock according to the MPI standard or not. And as far as I know, the code is deadlock-free.

Comment: The standard says the blocking version may cause deadlock, so it may cause deadlock. Your particular MPI implementation may or may not deadlock depending on how they chose to implement things, but it's still incorrect to assume the blocking version will work everywhere.

Comment: From the standard: "Once an MPI operation is *enabled*, the operation must eventually complete." Here, the 1st call of process 0 and 1st call of process 1 are enabled by each other, so they will return. Then the 2nd call of process 1 and 1st call of process 2 are enabled by each other, so they will return. All calls return successfully in this way.

Comment: There are cases with overlapping communicators where blocking collective operations can cause deadlock. But I'm pretty sure this example is not one of them.